# Multimatch query on documents with multiple IPs

Tags: elasticsearch

I have following sample documents:

```
doc1
{
 "privateIp": "172.31.97.21",
 "instanceType": "production",
 "publicIp": "172.31.8.12",
 "avZone": "cmp019",
 "instanceId": "i-00000039",
 "instanceState": "running",
 "description": "common node"
}

doc2
{
 "privateIp": "172.31.97.12",
 "instanceType": "production",
 "publicIp": "172.31.8.4",
 "avZone": "cmp019",
 "instanceId": "i-00000038",
 "instanceState": "running",
 "description": "common node"
}
```

And I need to query it with multimatch query. However when I execute following query:

```
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match" : {
         "query":    "172.31.8.12", 
         "fields": ["instanceId", "description", "privateIp", "publicIp"],
         "operator": "AND",
         "type": "cross_fields",
         "lenient": true
}}}
```

I get back both documents which is undesirable - I only want **doc1**. Moreover **doc2** has higher score than **doc1**.

Both **publicIp** and **privateIp** are mapped as IP Type.

How can I get back only doc1?

Answer (score 0):

**cross_fields** is used for term-centric matching

by default the analyzer will split the values of Ip into multiple parts with separator dot

you should make Ip field as not analyzed in mapping in order to match the entire Ip

Comment: As far as I know IP Type does not take **not_analyzed** setting, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520892/how-to-execute-an-ip-range-query-filter).

Comment: can you share the mapping details of particular field and your output results with scores you have got if possible

Comment: I can only share subset of the source document. However when I have done the exercise it works fine with the subset; it also works fine with the data mentioned above. I suspect that it is mapping issue, but I will continue digging and come back alter.